# SQLITE: How to get One row from table + get rest of rows in different order

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with below rows.

```
rowid  type value
1       A    13
2       A    14
3       B    12
4       B    15
5       C    17
6       C    16
```

I want to get the bigest value of type A first, it's rowid=2, then others in order by value DESC, the rowids are 56413

How to implement it sqlite? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to do this only in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when type = 'A' and
                    value = (select max(t2.value) from t t2 where t2.type = 'A')
               then 1 else 2
          end),
         value desc;
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select max(value) as maxvalue from t where type = 'A'
     ) ta
order by (case when t.type = 'A' and t.value = ta.maxvalue then 1 else 2 end),
         value desc;
```

Comment: This is better than a group by

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the UNION clause to join 2 queries in one.

```
SELECT Type, Value FROM YourTableName WHERE rowID = 2
UNION
SELECT Type, Value FROM YourTableName WHERE rowID != 2 ORDER BY value DESC
```